# Checksums don't match is that bad?

Tags: checksum, sha1

I recently started looking at VisualStudio 2012.
I tried downloading it from the official Microsoft link but it failed with some errors. As of some suggestions I downloaded the DVD5 ISO image to install it offline. I used JDownloader because it was too big and I wanted to pause/resume the download.
However when the download finished the SHA1 checksums didn't match.
Does that mean the file is corrupted and/or I have to redownload?

Checksum provided by microsoft:
F7688D0D8955BF321715A990854E8073206CCE17

The checksum I got:
eb90fbb91eb816b217519a7725e6b3fad46a5cc5

The error I got while downloading Visual Studio from the official link is "Couldn't locate package source" and it had the option to download from the internet but if I did that it just threw me the same error.

Comment: What errors did you recieve exactly?  If the checksums do not match then the file is unlikely complete.

Comment: @Ramhound I got "Couldnt locate package source" or something and it gave me the option to download it but if I selected that it just threw me back at the menu also jdownloader says that its done

Comment: Update your question with the information.  If you have a screenshot post it in the comments and somebody will inline the screenshot for you.

Comment: Did you try downloading it again?  If so, did you get the same hash/results? Did you try using the ISO at all? Did it work?

Comment: @techie007 I didnt try the iso because I wanted to make sure its ok before installing and I might try redownloading it because its 1.4 GB and my connection is prety slow but I guess i might try.

Comment: You can open and look at an ISO without 'installing' anything. If something like 7-zip can't open the ISO, then it's probably corrupted.

Comment: @techie007 winrar can open it without any problems

Answer (score 3):

The checksum is a hash created from running a mathematical function against the file.  The idea is that if a file differs in ANY way from the original, the hash will not be the same.

If the hash is different, what you know is that it isn't exactly the same as the source file from MS.  This could be a warning that the file has been modified (possibly to contain malware) or it might have just been packaged differently.

You should make sure you are getting it from a trusted source before opening or using the file.

Comment: Im getting this from microsoft but using JDownloader download manager.

Comment: In that case, it's most likely the download didn't complete successfully.